# pl/sql Creating temporary global tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to PL/SQL and I need to create a temp table from 3 tables and the record set be available for a report, I need the recorset only for the duration of the sesion.  I would like
to know what is the best way since I had heard that temporary global tables are not the best option.

- table1: `fields t1.pnum, t1.dnum t1.amount, t1.c_amount`
- table2: `fields t2.pnum, t2.dnum t2.amount, t2.c_amount`
- table3: `fields t3.pnum, t3.dnum t3.amount, t3.c_amount`

where table2 and table3 results union to table1 by pnum

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You create the global temporary table as a regular schema object, not "on the fly" with PL/SQL. Then you insert into it and select from it. The data you nsert is only visible to your session, and when you either commit or disconnect or delete the data, it is gone.

However, are you sure that you need it? You can often do without a GTT in favour of Common Table Expressions (WITH clauses).

Comment: Thank you David, I think creating a schema object is the best way, I am not familiar with Common Table Expressions, could you please elaborate on the topic? your help is very much appreciated